# Can't access my website in Network from VM

Tags: iis, networking, ip, virtual-machine, hosting

I deployed a testing website on my host and want to access from VM.
I setup a network connection and both are connected to a home group.
I can share files form one to another using share folder.
I assigned IP to my website so that I may be able to access using its IP.
When I brows at local using IP. it run perfect.
But when I brows from VM. It gives me error This site can't be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I dig out and taken 3 steps. and my issue is solved.

1. I Turn off my windows firewall on host.
2. **Authentications:**
     i) In IIS I click on Authentication.
   ii) Anonymous Authentications Enabled.
3. **IP Address and Domain Restrictions:**
    In IIS Click on **IP Address and Domain Restrictions** and Add IP address of VM or
   any PC
    from where I want to access.
    and now it worked.

Answer (score 0):

in your VM environment, you need to check networking configurations and permissions.
could be a lot of things, if you could add a picture it would be easier to tell you. if you can't, see if your connection is bridged or not. 
also, a good thing to check is that your router has an open port for your VM and allows another connection inside your subnet.